# Flutter Navigate to a Page as Root page

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Currently, I have Navigation Stack

**PageA => PageB => PageC**

I want to pus Push PageD as the root page

So the final result would be

**=>PageD**

How can I achieve that using Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` like this-

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/screenD', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

(Basically pop all - A, B and C and then push D)
Refer [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog right here.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Your exact scenario is at `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` section.

Answer (score 0):

Push a root page:

```dart
static void pushRootPage({
  required BuildContext context,
  required Widget page,
}) {
  var router = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page);
  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, router, (route) => false);
}
```